# assign values to new column in data.table by reference to character string in existing column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a table of variables describing courses taken by uni students. It is already in the data.table format.

One of the columns, SCA_TITLE, contains the course name. This contains character strings with names like: "Bachelor of Information Systems" "Bachelor of Laws and Bachelor of Information Systems.

I want to create a new column called "DOUBLE DEGREE" which assigns 1 where students are taking double degrees and assigns 0 where they are not.

So basically where one of the below conditions is met for SCA_TITLE

- has the string "and Bachelor", or;
- the word Bachelor is repeated twice

the value in the new column needs to be set equal to 1, and if not, it needs to be set equal to zero.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The SCA_TITLE column looks like this. There are 465K observations and 65 variables:

204: Honours degree of Bachelor of Science (Environmental Management)
205:       Honours degree of Bachelor of Science (Medical Bioscience)
206:  Honours degree of Bachelor of Science (Science Scholar Program)
207:                        Honours degree of Bachelor of Visual Arts
208:               Honours degree of Bachelor of Visual Communication

Comment: Please consider to show few lines of your dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,DOUBLE_DEGREE:=as.numeric(grepl('and Bachelor',
                                        SCA_TITLE)|.N>1),by=ID]
df 
df
 #    ID                       SCA_TITLE DOUBLE_DEGREE
 # 1:  3                   Bachelor of A             0
 # 2:  2                   Bachelor of B             1
 # 3:  5                   Bachelor of C             1
 # 4:  4                   Bachelor of D             0
 # 5:  5                   Bachelor of E             1
 # 6:  7                   Bachelor of F             0
 # 7:  2 Bachelor of G and Bachelor of N             1
 # 8:  6                   Bachelor of H             1
 # 9:  6                   Bachelor of I             1
 #10:  2                   Bachelor of J             1
```

#### Update

In case you have other `degrees` and need to consider only `Bachelor`, `and Bachelor`

```
  setDT(df1)[, DOUBLE_DEGREE:= as.numeric(sum(grepl('Bachelor',
             SCA_TITLE))>1|grepl('and Bachelor', SCA_TITLE)), by=ID]

 df1
 #    ID                                         SCA_TITLE DOUBLE_DEGREE
 #1:  3                   Honours degree of Bachelor of A             0
 #2:  2                   Honours degree of Bachelor of B             1
 #3:  5                   Honours degree of Bachelor of C             1
 #4:  4                   Honours degree of Bachelor of D             0
 #5:  5                  Honours  degree of Bachelor of E             1
 #6:  7                   Honours degree of Bachelor of F             0
 #7:  9 Honours degree of Bachelor of G and Bachelor of N             1
 #8:  6                                       Some degree             0
 #9:  6                   Honours degree of Bachelor of I             0
 #10: 2                   Honours degree of Bachelor of J             1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(3L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 2L), 
SCA_TITLE = c("Bachelor of A", "Bachelor of B", "Bachelor of C", 
"Bachelor of D", "Bachelor of E", "Bachelor of F", 
"Bachelor of G and Bachelor of N",     "Bachelor of H", "Bachelor of I",
"Bachelor of J")), .Names = c("ID", "SCA_TITLE"), row.names = c(NA, -10L),
class = "data.frame")

df1 <-  structure(list(ID = c(3, 2, 5, 4, 5, 7, 9, 6, 6, 2), SCA_TITLE =
c("Honours degree of Bachelor of A", "Honours degree of Bachelor of B",
"Honours degree of Bachelor of C", "Honours degree of Bachelor of D", 
"Honours  degree of Bachelor of E", "Honours degree of Bachelor of F", 
"Honours degree of Bachelor of G and Bachelor of N", "Some degree", 
"Honours degree of Bachelor of I", "Honours degree of Bachelor of J"
 )), .Names = c("ID", "SCA_TITLE"), row.names = c(NA, -10L),
 class = "data.frame")
```